# JQuery and AJAX .post return undefined index in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I realize this question has been answered numerous times, but I can't seem to find a solution that works. I've been stuck on this all day and am about to lose my mind. Everything seems to work fine, the data is correct, it just isn't getting passed to the PHP. I've tried using both .post with jquery and ajax.

The HTML and JQuery/AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Today's Clients</title>

<link href="../_css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clientSubmit").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var clientInformation = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('IRCpopulatecheckin.php',clientInformation,clientForm);
        function clientForm(data) {
            if (data!='') {
                $('#clientform').load("IRCpopulatecheckin.php");
                alert(clientInformation);
            } else {
                alert("your data returned nothing!!! rewrite the code...");
            }
        } // end clientForm
    }); // end .submit  
}); // end ready

/*

    $(".clientSubmit").submit(function() {
        var clientInformation = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'IRCpopulatecheckin.php',
        data: { 'clientInformation':clientInformation },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $('#clientform').load("IRCpopulatecheckin.php");
            alert(clientInformation);
            } // end result
        }) // end .ajax
    return false;
    }); // end .submit

*/
</script>

<style>

/* css to style and remove everything but text */
    #hiddenInput {
                position    :relative;
                width       :0px;
                height      :8px;
                top         :-40px;
                left        :-230px;260
                }
    input[name="dailyClient"] {
                background-color: white;
                border: none;
                font-weight :bold;
                font-family :sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;  
                color: black;
                cursor: default;
                line-height: normal;
                padding: 6px;
                text-align: center;
                text-shadow: none;
                white-space: pre;
                }

    input[name="dailyClient"]:hover {
                color: blue;
                }
</style>                
<body>
<div id="clientform"></div>

<?php 

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['DATE'])) {
    $DATE = $_POST['DATE'];
    }else{
        $DATE = date('Y-m-d');
         }

require_once 'IRCconfig.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_CHECKIN WHERE DATE>='$DATE' ORDER BY F_NAME ASC";
    $result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        echo <<<_END
        <pre>
            <div id="hiddenInput"><div style="display:none">

            <form class="clientSubmit" name="clientSubmit" action="IRCpopulatecheckin.php" method="POST">

            <input type="hidden" name="DATE"   value="$row[0]">
            <input type="hidden" name="F_NAME" value="$row[1]">
            <input type="hidden" name="M_NAME" value="$row[2]">
            <input type="hidden" name="L_NAME" value="$row[3]">

            </div></div>

            <input type="submit" name="dailyClient" value="$row[1] $row[2] $row[3]"></form>
            </pre>
_END;
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Relevant PHP code

```
<?php  
//IRCpopulatecheckin.php
ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'IRCconfig.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

//Doesn't work
if(!isset($_POST['DATE'])){
    echo "something is wrong here"; 
}else{
    $DATE=$_POST["DATE"]; 
     }
if(!isset($_POST['F_NAME'])){
    echo "something is wrong here"; 
}else{
    $DATE=$_POST["F_NAME"]; 
     }
if(!isset($_POST['M_NAME'])){
    echo "something is wrong here"; 
}else{
    $M_NAME=$_POST["M_NAME"]; 
     }
if(!isset($_POST['L_NAME'])){
    echo "something is wrong here"; 
}else{
    $L_NAME=$_POST["L_NAME"]; 
     }


/*Doesn't work

$DATE   = isset($_GET['DATE'])   ? $_GET['DATE']   : $_POST['DATE'];
$F_NAME = isset($_GET['F_NAME']) ? $_GET['F_NAME'] : $_POST['F_NAME'];
$M_NAME = isset($_GET['M_NAME']) ? $_GET['M_NAME'] : $_POST['M_NAME'];
$L_NAME = isset($_GET['L_NAME']) ? $_GET['L_NAME'] : $_POST['L_NAME'];

*/


/* Doesn't work

if(isset($_POST['DATE']))
    $DATE = $_POST['DATE'];
if(isset($_POST['F_NAME']))
    $F_NAME = $_POST['F_NAME'];
if(isset($_POST['M_NAME']))
    $M_NAME = $_POST['M_NAME'];
if(isset($_POST['L_NAME']))
    $L_NAME = $_POST['L_NAME'];

*/

$query  = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_CHECKIN WHERE DATE='$DATE' AND F_NAME='$F_NAME' AND M_NAME='$M_NAME' AND L_NAME='$L_NAME'";   
$result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);
```

Comment: what is `$(".clientSubmit")`? Is that the submit button? In that case, `$(this).serialize()` will not produce anything useful, because `$(this)` gets you the submit button, not the form itself. Either way, you should `console.log(clientInformation)` before you send the post request, just to make sure that you're sending the data you think you're sending.

Comment: additionally you'll need to build a $data array of fields in your php and echo json_encode($data); them in order to get the data into your javascript. This way, on the javascript end you can do a var data = JSON.parse(data); to get a javascript object of the original php data array. Hope this make sense.

Comment: The OP has it correct: `clientSubmit` is the class of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".clientSubmit").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var $form = $(this); 
       var clientInfo = $form.serialize();

       console.log(clientInfo);

       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'IRCpopulatecheckin.php',
          data: clientInfo,
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
              // try seeing if you can get this alert to pop up first
              alert(result);
              //$('#clientform').load("IRCpopulatecheckin.php");
          }
       }); // don't forget semi-colon
   });
});
```

Comment: This code returns the AJAX variables correctly in the alert statement, but still does not pass them to the PHP. I'll read up on json_encode and see if I can figure something out from there.

Comment: What do you mean it "returns the AJAX variables correctly in the alert statement"?

Comment: So, I modified the code to include this statement - data: JSON.stringify(clientInfo), - and added this, var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
$clientInfo = json_decode($_POST['clientInfo']); to my PHP. However, I am still getting the undefined index errors, with addition of a NULL from the var_dump. $clientInfo also returns nothing. I picked up the book AJAX and PHP - building responsive web applications, which I will get started on, but in the mean time. Any suggestions?

Comment: The alert statement returns DATE=2014-12-03+09%3A08%3A54&F_NAME=Johnny&M_NAME=Darby&L_NAME=Cache, which is the correct information.

Comment: The PHP code to print_r an array returns Array ( ). *edited for unnecessary words